# Feeding time data to tf.estimator: `input_fn` must be callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator, automl

#### Goal

I want to [mod this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/adanet/blob/master/adanet/examples/tutorials/customizing_adanet.ipynb) to consume [this time series dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/human+activity+recognition+using+smartphones#) instead of the run-of-the-mill image data.

#### Approach

I have identified several approaches to get the data into the `tf.estimator` API.
The most convenient (because using `.from_generator` is guesswork...) was to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_data_ndarray)` as follows:

```
trnX, trnY, tstX, tstY = load_dataset()
trnXl = trnX.tolist()
tstXl = tstX.tolist()
tstYl = tstY.tolist()
trnYl = trnY.tolist()
trndataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trnXl, trnYl))
tstdataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tstXl, tstYl))
...
def _input_fn(partition):
    if partition == "train":
        dst = trndataset
    elif partition == "predict":
        dst = tstdataset
    else:
        dst = tstdataset

    return dst
```

#### Error/Issue

> TypeError: `input_fn` must be callable, given: DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((128, 9), (6,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>

#### Reproduction

I use paperspace instance. If you have an account you **can take a look** [here](https://www.paperspace.com/dawg/notebook/prx7ggxh5).

1. If not, get [full code in this gist:](https://gist.github.com/le-dawg/7549af80516379f6c58bc8d2381486a7).
2. Dataset from [2](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/human+activity+recognition+using+smartphones#).

Setup:

- Tensorflow 1.15
- Python 3.6.8
- Eager execution: off (adanet library won't handle it).

**Error appears when calling:**

```
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
estimator,
train_spec=tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    input_fn=_input_fn("train"),
    max_steps=TRAIN_STEPS),
eval_spec=tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
    input_fn=_input_fn("test"),
    steps=None,
    start_delay_secs=1,
    throttle_secs=1,  
))
```

### What now?

I see no path forward using the approach of creating a tf.data.Dataset since it seems the input function ("create an input function that returns a dataset") is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This may help someone in the future but it doesn't solve my deeper issue.

**In order to make the input_fn callable but still accept arguments, there are two options: wrap the function call in a lambda operator OR wrap the actual input_fn inside another input_fn that returns the inner function.**

```
classifier.train(
input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train, train_y, training=True),
steps=5000)
```

> Note that you wrap up your input_fn call in a lambda to capture the arguments while providing an input function that takes no arguments, as expected by the Estimator

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/premade